# If element not in vector, add elements to vector, then search vector again

Tags: r, vector, match

A website has a list of values that i have scraped into a vector. I want to search this vector for myColor.

```
myColor <- "teal"
myVector <- c("blue", "red", "yellow")
match(myColor, myVector) # returns NA
```

If that match function returns NA, selenium will click a "more" button showing new values in the list. These new values will be scraped and added to myVector, and then I want to search for myColor again.

```
myVector <- c(myVector, "black", "brown", "grey")
match(myColor, myVector) # still returns NA
```

This process should repeat until myColor is found in the vector (it will always be found eventually), and the match function returns the position of myColor in myVector.

```
myVector <- c(myVector, "purple", "green", "teal")
match(myColor, myVector) # should return position of "teal"
```

I assume it would involve some type of loop and/or an if statement, but I have not been able to figure out a way to do this without manually doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following structure:

```r
myColor <- "teal"
myVector <- c("blue", "red", "yellow")
isFound <- FALSE

while (!isFound) {
    matchResult <- match(myColor, myVector)
    if(is.na(matchResult)){
        # scraping using selenium
        seleniumDriver$action
        newVec <- seleniumDriver$getVector
        # add scraped vector to myVector
        myVector <- c(myVector, newVec)
    } else {
        isFound <- TRUE
    }
}
```